# Saving part of an audio file (Java)

Tags: java

While playing an audio file (.wav) I want, if I resort to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, to stop the playback and save part of the audio file in a file called "file2.wav".

Here's the thread I'd like to add to my code.
Unfortunately it doesn't work at all.

---

```
class myThread extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        try {
            PipedOutputStream poStream = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream piStream = new PipedInputStream();
            poStream.connect(piStream);
            File cutaudioFile = new File ("file2.wav");

            AudioInputStream ais =
              new AudioInputStream(piStream,
                                   AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                                   cutaudioFile);
            poStream.write(ais,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,cutaudioFile);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end run
} // end myThread
```

---

Comment: You're trying to save the unplayed part of the wav file to disk when you hit Ctrl-C?

Comment: Is your `new AudioInputStream(...)` part correct? Constructor shown at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#AudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20long) takes a `long` as the third parameter and not a `File`

Answer (score 0):

This should be basically what you want.  It uses a shutdown hook.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CtrlCAudio
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
  {
    final File inputAudio = new File(args[0]);
    final File outputAudio = new File(args[1]);
    // First, we get the format of the input file
    final AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(inputAudio).getType();
    // Then, we get a clip for playing the audio.
    final Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
    // We get a stream for playing the input file.
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputAudio);
    // We use the clip to open (but not start) the input stream
    c.open(ais);
    // We get the format of the audio codec (not the file format we got above)
    final AudioFormat audioFormat = ais.getFormat();
    // We add a shutdown hook, an anonymous inner class.
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        // We're now in the hook, which means the program is shutting down.
        // You would need to use better exception handling in a production application.
        try
        {
          // Stop the audio clip.
          c.stop();
          // Create a new input stream, with the duration set to the frame count we reached.  Note that we use the previously determined audio format
          AudioInputStream startStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputAudio), audioFormat, c.getLongFramePosition());
          // Write it out to the output file, using the same file type.
          AudioSystem.write(startStream, fileType, outputAudio);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    // After setting up the hook, we start the clip.
    c.start();
  }
}
```