# Cut an audio file

Tags: android, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing audio / rerecording part of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069769/editing-audio-rerecording-part-of-a-file)

I need to cut an audio file, that is available on sdcard. Cut means I want to take some portion of a audio file to set a ringtone. I can set ringtone, but how I can do cut an audio file from any position?

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069769/editing-audio-rerecording-part-of-a-file

Comment: thanks, yes I saw this. and it is "Ringdroid".

Comment: What audio file formats do you need to support?

Answer (score 3):

Basically with pure Android SDK, it is not possible. We have to use Java and if any one does not want to do from scratch, he/she can use the [Ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) open source project.